# What is the usage of USING() function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables which I want to join, and I can achieve it by 2 ways:

*Customers*:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| CustomerID | Name               | Address            | City         |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|          1 | Julie Smith        | 25 Oak Street      | Airport West |
|          2 | Alan Wong          | 1/47 Haines Avenue | Box Hill     |
|          3 | Michelle Arthur    | 357 North Road     | Yarraville   |
|          4 | Geogrge Napolitano | 177 Melbourne Road | Coburg       |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

*Orders*:

```
+---------+------------+--------+------------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | Amount | Date       |
+---------+------------+--------+------------+
|       1 |          3 |  69.98 | 2019-04-02 |
|       2 |          1 |  49.99 | 2019-04-15 |
|       3 |          2 |  74.99 | 2019-05-19 |
|       4 |          3 |  24.99 | 2019-05-01 |
+---------+------------+--------+------------+
```

Now I would like to select only those customers, that has *no* order placed (`OrderID == null`). That is only the `Geogrge Napolitano`. So I can use 2 ways:

```
mysql> select Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Name
    -> from Customers left join Orders 
    -> on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
    -> where Orders.OrderID is null;
```

or

```
mysql> select Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Name
    -> from Customers left join Orders
    -> using(CustomerID)
    -> where Orders.OrderID is null;
```

Now for me. It seems that `=` in first case (`Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID`), is *exactly* the same as `USING()` that Id. But is it always that case? In what other cases I can use the mysql function `USING()` ?

Comment: *In what other cases I can use the mysql function USING() ?* USING is **not** a function. It is a clause. And it does not belong to MySQL only. *It seems that = in first case (Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID), is exactly the same as USING() that Id.* Exactly - no. Replace `SELECT {columns} FROM ...` in your queries with `SELECT * FROM ...` - and you will find one little difference.

Comment: You may (or may not) use the USING clause if and only if the joining field has exactly the same name on both sides of the join, and since it's a common practice to name that way fields related to id fields my guess is that has been included to simplify the coding.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use Using, column names which connects two tables are needed to be same.

so,

```
 on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```

equals to

```
using(CustomerID)
```

when column names are same on both sides.

Comment: So it amounts to a convenience shorthand for situations where columns are identically named

Comment: Nope, that's not the only difference - see the accepted snswer from the duplicate question.

Comment: @ysth Oracle Database, PostgreSQL and a lot of another DBMSs supports USING...

Comment: @ysth using construct is part of the sql 92 standard, it is not a mysqlism.

Comment: @Shadow nice, someone had told me different.  so irritating that the standard isn't free